# How to add an item to a List<> in View in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, list, model-view-controller, razor, model

In the view I have a Model that consists of 2 Lists. The `Model.Ingredients` is full of Ingredient objects, the second one `UsedIngredients` is initialized but empty.

If the user clicks on an ingredient i want to add it to the empty list, because i want to pass that list to a partial view.

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Ingredients)
{
    if (item.Type == "spirit")
    {
        <a onclick="@Model.UsedIngredients.Add(item)">@item.Name</a>
    }
}
```

If I Try this I get an error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'object'.

I have the list initialized correctly i think:

```
List<Models.Extended.Ingredient> list = new List<Models.Extended.Ingredient>();
creator.UsedIngredients = list;
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok turns out I’m kinda dumb because why would it work? We cannot run server side code onclick action like this. So I have to use session variables and httpPost method.